# Can I use MOSI, MISO, SCK pings for reading input in AT89S52?

Tags: microcontroller, flash, input, io

I am doing a custom keyboard for my project. It has totally 22 keys.

I am using AT89S52 microcontroller. I have allocated P0.0 TO P0.7 AND P2.0 TO P2.7 AND P1.2, P1.3, P1.4 (totally 19 pins) which are completely available for I/O operation.

I have 3 more keys to read input. So, in this case can I use MOSI, MISO, SCK pins which I use during flash programming.

And even INT0, INT1, T0, T1 if I require more inputs in future?

Comment: Have you considered multiplexing? You could read 25 keys with 10 pins using a simple square matrix.

Comment: ohh really!! I have no idea about that. Let me check that. Thanks for sharing an useful information. If you have some useful references kindly share.

Comment: Hi @brhans,

Also please tell me whether these MISO, MOSI & SCK pings can be used?

Comment: While I'm not familiar with that particular 8051 variant, it would be very unusual for those pins to be dedicated to only SPI functionality. As long as you're not trying to use them as both SPI & keyboard at the same time you should be able to use them as Px.x just like the others.

Comment: great! let me try that. I read about the multiplexing. It is quite interesting and a good logic indeed.  But I have some complications where I am not sure whether I can use multiplexing.

Comment: Between the good answers from brhans and @delta12, you have the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general many pins you find on a microcontroller have a primary purpose (IO) and a secondary purpose (like the SPI pins or INT pins). You can use SPI pins (MISO, MOSI, SCK) as IO pins as you would use any other pin although you *might* not be able to program the MC because of possible interference from the IO line, but if you use a PDIP version of the chip (through hole), the easiest solution (not the best though!) is to simply remove the chip and program it on a breadboard, then reinsert it into the circuit (use an IC socket). The interrupt pins also work as general IO pins unless you configure them to do otherwise.

I'd also suggest exploring the possiblity of using a newer model of your microcontroller because the AT89S52 is quite outdated.

Comment: Can you suggest some latest microcontroller which would cost not more than 2$

Comment: Well, probably the best low-power microcontrollers are the Atmel's ATmega or ATtiny series (you can see all available models [http://www.atmel.com/products/microcontrollers/avr/megaavr.aspx](here)).They however use a different architecture than AT89 series chips and if you chose that chip specifically for the thing you want to do (it has some exclusive features maybe) you should stick with it. However if you can, you should use an AVR chip because they are much more modern and are used really widely today, in Arduinos as well.

Comment: oh really! Many thanks for detailed information @DELTA12.

I will try AVR chip.

Comment: Also pls suggest the basic model of AVR chip. simply with features such as I/O pins upto 25 (excluding these SPI / MOSI / MISO confusions). Also with UART feature